# Range function syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I'm trying with a range function sample but "invalid syntax" come up. Thanks

```
for i in range(5):
    print('i is now:', i)
i is now 0
i is now 1
i is now 2
i is now 3
i is now 4
```

Comment: Please post your exact error.

Comment: Are you typing/pasting the `i is now 0` part into the Python interpreter? That's the *output* of that code, not part of it.

Comment: line 3 i is now 0 syntax error: invalid syntax

Comment: Lines 1 and 2 are the code; the rest is what the code should be outputting. Only include lines 1 and 2 when trying to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your code that is in code section of this post.
You will get answer as output section of this post.

**Code**

```
for i in range(5):
    print('i is now:', i)
```

**Output**

```
i is now 0
i is now 1
i is now 2
i is now 3
i is now 4
```